# Boost Interprocess Security Error while opening Shared Memory File

Tags: c++, boost, vector, ipc, boost-interprocess

I'm trying to use `Boost` Interprocess mechanisms, specifically `shared memory` for `vectors`.

So in my client application which tried to access the `shared memory` file, to read the shared data, all I get is an `error_info` which points to `Security Error`, when it tried to open the shared memory, as in the attached image.

[image]

I'm not certain what issue this points to, or whether it needs permissions, and if so, what permissions are required. I'm using Windows 8.1 with UAC turned off.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?   I get the same error on linux.

Comment: This was because of synchronization locks. The application was trying to access the shared memory a the same time it was being written, so some locks came into the picture and denied access to the memory. I'd suggest you do a check to see if proper synch is going on.